# Why "mmadoc.tex" is not executing?

Tags: document-classes

I have downloaded `mmaaut.cls` file from [here](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/10.1002/(ISSN)1099-1476/homepage/latex_class_files.htm) and I saved it in folder where I use to place all my other Latex work file, but when I tried to run file `mmadoc.tex` in my WinEdt compiler, an error message occurred as

> 1.4319   \ProcessKeyvalOption{Hyp}

What does it mean ? Why I unable to execute my `mmadoc.tex` file ?

Comment: You have to use `latex` to compile it, not `pdflatex` or remove the `dvips` option in the `hyperref` option list. And `WinEdt` is an editor (so they say ;-)), but no compiler and has **nothing** to do with this problem as long as you have correctly configured it!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: It worked !!!! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `mmadoc.tex` uses

```
\usepackage[dvips,...]{hyperref}% Shortened here...
```

This is no error as long as `latex` is used and not `pdflatex` or `lualatex` since those are running in PDF mode.

The example below is the shortest one that has the same error:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[dvips]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

> ! Package hyperref Error: Wrong DVI mode driver option `dvips',
>   (hyperref)                because pdfTeX or LuaTeX is running in PDF
>   mode.
>
> See the hyperref package documentation for explanation. Type  H
>     for immediate help.  ...
>
> ```
> l.4362 \ProcessKeyvalOptions{Hyp}
>                               ?
> ```

The `\ProcessKeyvalOptions` checks for all options given to `hyperref` and the relevant code lines that provide the error message are

```
\def\HyOpt@CheckDvi#1{%
  \ifHy@DviMode
    \expandafter\ltx@firstofone
  \else
    \Hy@Error{%
      Wrong DVI mode driver option `#1',\MessageBreak
      because \Hy@DviErrMsg
    }\@ehc
    \expandafter\ltx@gobble
  \fi
}
```

In short: If the file should be run with latex, everything is alright, if `pdflatex` or `lualatex` is used, remove `dvips` from the `hyperref` option list.